# How to secure a $_POST submit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I know a lot on how to secure a Core PHP submit POST.

This time, I am using wordpress and I am creating my custom plugin. One of the things I want to make sure is how to secure my form the wordpress recommends.

Using PHP, here is a sample PHP submit form and I want to implement this in WP.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) //how to secure this submit form
{ 
   echo $_POST['input']; //how to secure this input
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="input">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: submit over https. not sure what "secure" means here

Comment: @nogad. secure the form from hijacking, xxs, etc.

Comment: There is nonce in word press, try to implement nonce in your form for security.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to [sanitize and escape user data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data).

Comment: How about securing the submit button?

Comment: Same thing, posted data is posted data. It's atypical to use any posted data from a submit button object itself.